# How to install Service Pack 2 of SQL Server 2008 Express R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

there is a known bug in the installation routine of SQL Server 2008 Express R2 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2387686), which is supposed to be fixed by service pack 2. As my installation fails, I do not know how to apply the Service Pack to a piece of software which is not installed.

Any hints how to proceed ?

Rergards, Uwe

Comment: This one should be on ServerFault (voted to move).

Comment: There is no SP2 for SQL Server 2008 R2 yet, as far as I know - not even a SP1..... that link talks about SP2 for SQL Server 2008 - not 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOTE:** This is an old answer. Service packs of SQL 2008 R2 are now available for download.*

There is **NO** SP2 for SQL 2008 R2. There is an SP2 for SQL 2008.

EDIT: The fix for your issue is in CU 5 and above for SQL 2008 R2.

1. So you will need to download [SQL 2008 R2 CU6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2489376).
2. Slipstream the SQL 2008 R2 CU 6 into SQL 2008 R2 Express installation package as per this [post](http://windowsmasher.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/optimized-sql-server-2008-r2-express-installation/).
3. Install SQL 2008 R2 Express using the updated installation files.

Comment: SP1 for SQL 2008 R2 is available now.